# ios - How to declare URL in NSURLConnection delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm following this link http://www.stevesaxon.me/posts/2011/window-external-notify-in-ios-uiwebview/ to get access token,but how to declare URL here

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

if(_data)

{

NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_data
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [_data release];
        _data = nil;

        // prepend the HTML with our custom JavaScript
        content = [ScriptNotify stringByAppendingString:content];

        //Here how to declare URL
        [_webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:_url];
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a NSURL in this way: `NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourdomain.com/something"];`

Comment: I've created like this NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://converse.accesscontrol.windows"];,instead of initWithString can we use some other

Comment: Sorry I tried URLWithString,I'm getting en error 'SIGABRT'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given example, _url is a member variable. Declare it in your property list and assign it in `[webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:]` callback as `_url = [[request URL] retain];`

And for the love of all that you consider holy, please indent your code properly.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply,have you seen that link,if([scheme isEqualToString:@"acs"]) condition fails

Comment: No clue. Post another question, someone else may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

use this for baseURL:-   NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

Comment: `fileURLWithPath:` is only used for local paths.